# Dynamically insert variable into object path in JavaScript and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, object

I don't know if I'm understanding this concept wrong, but hours of searching hasn't yielded anything.

I want to dynamically load fields for a form based on a 'type' selected by a user from a dropdown. This is bound to the variable "currentType" through angular. That part works.

```
currentType = //whatever the user chose. Will evaluate to either "category1" or "category2"
currentFields = {}
fields = {
           'category1': {
                          propertyInfo {
                                        'label1'
                                        'label2'
                                        'label3'
                                        'label4'
           'category2': {
                          propertyInfo {
                                        'label5'
                                        'label6'
                                        'label7'
                                        'label8'
```

What I want to happen is when the type is selected the fields will be loaded. So:

```
currentFields = field."currentType".propertyInfo
```

I cannot figure out how to insert that variable into the object path. I keep getting errors about field not having the property "currentType".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be as simple as this (thanks to the dynamic nature of JS):

```
currentFields = field[currentType].propertyInfo
```

In case you didn't know, it works like this. If you have an object:

```
var foo = {
  bar: "42"
}
```

value `"42"` is accessible as either `foo.bar` or `foo['bar']`.

Comment: The problem is my variable "currentType" won't be defined when the page loads. It needs the user input. So when the page loads I get an error saying `ReferenceError: currentType is not defined`. Which is why I figured Angular might have some way to do that?

Comment: Well, that's a totally different problem. You can set a default value to `currentType` and handle that in your logic.

Comment: I made you a plunk, but plunkr failed me. In short, I used `$scope.$watch` to wait for user input and update `currentFields`

Comment: I've never used $watch before, but the documentation isn't shedding much light on the matter. Would I create a function in the controller that does `$scope.$watch(currentType, function(){ currentFields = field[currentType].propertyInfo })` ?

Comment: yeah, almost. `$scope.$watch('currentType', function(newVal) { $scope.currentFields = fields[newVal].propertyInfo})` (provided that you have fields `currentType` and `currentFields` on $scope and `fields` available otherwise (can be a local to this function) )